# Is it possible to replace merged files in one directory with redundant merged files from another directory in git?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, git-branch

I am still fairly new to Git, however I am trying to correct some of the **very** poor file structure I created previously and am unsure how.

Essentially what we have is this structure:

```
--original_folder
    -- file1
    -- file2
    -- file3
    -- file4
    -- file5
    --corrections_to_original_files_folder
        -- file1
        -- file2
        -- file3
        -- file4
        -- file5
```

`original_folder` represents the first merged branch, and `corrections_to_original_files_folder` represents the second merged branch (which, you guessed it, contains corrections to those files).

Obviously this was a really POOR way to do this. What I am trying to do to reduce redundancy is create a new branch, and essentially replace the contents of `original_folder` with the contents of `corrections_to_original_files_folder` and from there making additional edits.

I have tried several methods however, because this code is all merged, I cannot rely on any of the `git mv` methods, OR the `git checkout origin/BRANCH_TO_MOVE_FROM desired_file.py`.

Can anyone help me fix this dumpster fire?

Comment: When you say the code is merged, do you mean into a shared branch where you don't wish to rewrite any of the existing history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you can do exactly what you want to do, and you won't have any issues with it:

> What I am trying to do to reduce redundancy is create a new branch, and essentially replace the contents of `original_folder` with the contents of `corrections_to_original_files_folder` and from there making additional edits.

Let's assume your current duplicate folder structure as described exists on `main`. Now let's do what you said:

1. Make a new branch from main: `git switch -c new-branch main`
2. Copy the files in folder `corrections_to_original_files_folder` into `original_folder`. Git will show those files as all edited.
3. Delete the entire folder `corrections_to_original_files_folder`. Git will continue to show the other folder's files as edited, and additionally show all of these files as deleted.
4. Commit the change with a well worded commit message explaining what you did and why.
5. Work as you normally would.

Now you can merge `new-branch` into `main` if you wish so that everyone can have the fix right away, or you can continue working on `new-branch` and merge it later. As soon as `new-branch` is merged into `main` the "fix" will be applied.

Note this is pretty much exactly what you said you wanted to do. I'm guessing you just didn't realize that it would work, but it should.